How to handle circular dependencies with Jackson
I have a Spring Boot 3.3.4 application.
I have a User object which has a list of Item objects. The Item objects have references to the User object.
public class User {
    UUID id;

    String fullName;

    List<Item> items;
}

and
public class Item {
    UUID id;

    String name;

    User user;
}

When I list Item object I want the JSON to look like this:
[
   {
      "id": "faf210d5-1eb8-42a7-b3f3-a9546a1fef4f",
      "name":"book",
      "user": "eb3f856a-7c09-4ba2-875c-59af5d4dabcf"
   }
]

So, I want to have just an ID of a user owning this item, not the entire user object.
At the moment my JSON looks like this:
[
   {
      "id":"faf210d5-1eb8-42a7-b3f3-a9546a1fef4f",
      "name":"book",
      "user":{
         "id":"eb3f856a-7c09-4ba2-875c-59af5d4dabcf",
         "fullName":"John Doe",
         "items":[
            {
               "id":"faf210d5-1eb8-42a7-b3f3-a9546a1fef4f",
               "name":"book"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]

I tried various combinations using @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference and @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id"), but nothing seems to produce the desired behavior.
What should I do in order to get the desired outcome?

You could use @JsonValue or @JsonGetter
@JsonValue in User example:
    @JsonValue
    public String toJsonString(){
        return this.uuid;
    }

@JsonGetter in Item example:
    @JsonGetter("user")
    public String getUser() {
        return user.getUuid();
    }

